# What can nginx error mean: host not found in upstream "my.domain.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.conf

Tags: nginx

Upon a debian upgrade, a previously working configuration stopped working. The error I see with `systemctl status nginx.service` is `host not found in upstream "sync.mydomain.net"`:

```
Nov 20 01:05:40 mydomain.net systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 20 01:05:45 mydomain.net nginx[442]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "sync.mydomain.net" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myconfig.conf:9
Nov 20 01:05:46 mydomain.net nginx[442]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 20 01:05:46 mydomain.net systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 20 01:05:46 mydomain.net systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 01:05:46 mydomain.net systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

The relevant configuration file looks like that:

```
server {
    include myhttpsconfig.conf;
    server_name sync.mydomain.net;
    ssl_certificate     /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/sync.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/sync.mydomain.net/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        include myhttpssubdomain.conf;
        proxy_pass http://sync.mydomain.net:8383;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

What could be the reason for failure?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I do not fully understand what exactly the error is, but adding the empty second parameter to `server_name` definitely fixed the config for me:

```
server_name sync.mydomain.net "";
```

If you're going to use this solution, be sure to check what `Host` HTTP header does the server receive. This is a very incomplete answer, don't rely on this for security, check yourself

Comment: No, adding a parameter did not fix this - that's a different domain name from what you originally posted. However the error reported relates to the proxypass line in the config. You seem to have anonymized the data (incorrectly) from a value which was invalid at the time you tested it.